# Using cast in Hibernate Criteria?

Tags: hibernate, casting, criteria

I have a MySQL column as string and I have it like "`NAME123456`"

Now I would like to do a substring and cast it in Hibernate criteria and sort.

I would do it in normal SQL Query as.

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(column,LOCATE('NAME',column)+1) AS SIGNED)
```

But How would I do it in Criteria ?

Comment: have you figured out a way to do it in criteria ? Since I'm trying to implement advanced search and creating query can be real-complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when queries are complex, just use HQL. The end result will be the same. You can do sorting there too.